# How Docker will resolve hostname or IP present in properties file?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, mesos, marathon

I have 2 Spring Boot micro-service applications i.e web application and metastore application. This is the properties file for my web application.

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    prefix: classpath:/static/
  application:
    name: web-server
  profiles:
     active: native

server:
  port: ${port:8383}

---
host:
  metadata: http://10.**.**.***:5011
```

Dockerfile for web application:

```
FROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER **** <******>
ADD ./ms.console.ivu-ivu.1.0.1.jar /app/
CMD chmod +x /app/*
CMD ["java","-jar", "/app/ms.console.web-web.1.0.1.jar"]
EXPOSE 8383
```

Dockerfile for metadata application:

```
FROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER ******* <********>
ADD config/* /deploy/config/
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/config/*
COPY ./ms.metastore.1.0.1.jar /deploy/
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/ms.metastore.1.0.1.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","./deploy/ms.metastore.1.0.1.jar"]
EXPOSE 5011
```

I am using Mesos and Marathon for cluster management. The Marathon scripts for metastore is :-

```
{
  "id": "/ms-metastore",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 2000,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 0,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "*"
  ],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "forcePullImage": true,
      "image": "*****/****:ms-metastore",
      "parameters": [],
      "privileged": true
    },
    "volumes": [],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 5011,
        "hostPort": 0,
        "labels": {},
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "servicePort": 10000
      }
    ]
  },
  "networks": [
    {
      "mode": "container/bridge"
    }
  ],
  "portDefinitions": [],
  "fetch": [
    {
      "uri": "file:///etc/docker.tar.gz",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Web marathon:

```
{
  "id": "/ms-console",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 2000,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 0,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "*"
  ],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "forcePullImage": true,
      "image": "****/****:ms-console",
      "parameters": [],
      "privileged": true
    },
    "volumes": [],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 8383,
        "hostPort": 0,
        "labels": {},
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "servicePort": 10000
      }
    ]
  },
  "networks": [
    {
      "mode": "container/bridge"
    }
  ],
  "portDefinitions": [],
  "fetch": [
    {
      "uri": "file:///etc/docker.tar.gz",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Web application I am connecting to metastore with IP which is hard coded (mentioned in properties). I created docker images for both and run in my server. The metastore server now running in different machine, so my web application is unable to resolve this IP.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do here is expose `5011` as the host port on the metadata server running on "different machine" using `-p` -

`docker run -d -p 5011:5011 metadata_image ....`

Now your web application should be able to access metadata server by using `http://$different_machine_ip:5011/`

> $different_machine_ip = Metadata server IP

However since they need to be tightly coupled, i would suggest you run web app & metadata server on the same machine in case your metadata server is stateless.

Comment: I would not rely in IP addresses. Docker networking provides aliases for hosts through it own internal web Server. Either use those directly or use environment variables in the properties file

Comment: In that case you might want to use Swarm, KeyValue store & overlay network. Your current setup is prone to change, your question didn't specify that you want to use a DNS name.

Comment: Could me pls share me how I can use docker networking here

Comment: Ref - https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2016/05/03/setting-up-an-overlay-network-on-docker-without-swarm/ , this might help!